# How to select all the rows that are between a range of values in specific column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below sample df, and I'd like to select all the rows that are between a range of values in a specific column:

```
          0       1       2     3     4     5  index
0   -252.44 -393.07  886.72 -2.04  1.58 -2.41      0
1   -260.25 -415.53  881.35 -3.07  0.08 -1.66      1
2   -267.58 -412.60  893.07 -2.98 -1.15 -2.66      2
3   -279.30 -417.97  880.86 -1.15 -0.50 -1.37      3
4   -252.93 -395.51  883.30 -1.30  1.43  4.17      4
```

I'd like to get the below df (all the rows between index value of 1-3):

```
          0       1       2     3     4     5  index
1   -260.25 -415.53  881.35 -3.07  0.08 -1.66      1
2   -267.58 -412.60  893.07 -2.98 -1.15 -2.66      2
3   -279.30 -417.97  880.86 -1.15 -0.50 -1.37      3
```

How can I do it?

I tried the below which didn't work:

```
new_df = df[df['index'] >= 1 & df['index'] <= 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between min and max: use `between()`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[11,12,13]})
>>> df
   a   b
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13

>>> df[df.a.between(1,2)]
   a   b
0  1  11
1  2  12
```

Your attempt `new_df = df[df['index'] >= 1 & df['index'] <= 3]` is wrong in two places:

- it's `df.index`, not `df["index"]`
- when using multiple filters, use parentheses: `df[(df.index >= 1) & (df.index <= 3)]`